# Accesing internet with Host-Only network VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, internet, dhcp, freebsd

I have two VMs in my VirtualBox. Both are FreeBSD and should communicate between each other. I have created network with DHCP enabled and set like this:

```
Server Address  10.10.10.1
Server Mask 255.255.255.0
Lower Address Bound 10.10.10.100
Upper Address Bound 10.10.10.200
```

My VMs are pinging each other and getting right ip adress. This is what I must have and can´t change.

Now I want to access internet from one VM and I found that I must use two network cards but I don´t know how to set the second one. I am new with VirtualBox and this stuff so if you count with this in you answer I would appreciate that. And I have Windows 8 as host system if it´s matter.

Comment: Why not define the network adapter as NAT for all VMs and let your router handle the DHCP?

Comment: I have it like that because I need it for school project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the second network adapter is enabled. Also check the Advanced section for the second network adapter (Attached to: NAT) to make sure it's the same Adapter Type as the first network adapter (not a requirement but this way you will know the driver is loaded for it) and that Cable Connected is checked.

Verify in the FreeBSD guest that the /etc/rc.conf file has an entry to enable the added adapter. You'll see a line such as:

```
ifconfig_dc0="DHCP"
```

for the first and make sure there's an entry for the added adapter as well, example:

```
ifconfig_dc1="DHCP"
```

(replace the `dc` before the `1` with the same thing the current line has before the `0`)
then reboot the guest OS.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I knew that I must set something it settings and that It can´t be hard. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a network card is quite easy.

In the `Networking` section of the Virtual Machine's settings, choose an adapter tab. Tick `Enable Network Adapter`. For internet access, a NAT adapter is the easiest option. Then just click OK and you should be good to go!

[[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4D6Q.png)

---

See the [VirtualBox networking documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) for detailed descriptions of what each adapter does.

Note that the GUI for VirtualBox only supports four adapters. To add more, you can use the `VBoxManage modifyvm` command ([`modifyvm` networking documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#idp18854752)). `VBoxManage list systemproperties` will show the max number of network adapters available:

```
Maximum PIIX3 Network Adapter count:   8
Maximum ICH9 Network Adapter count:   36
```

`PIIX3` and `ICH9` are the two chipset options available on VirtualBox. PIIX3 is a very old chipset (and therefore does not support as many peripherals), but is the default for new VMs. You can change this in the `System` settings of the VM.

Comment: This is what I tried when I found that I must use two cards. Just added second card with NAT adapter but it didn´t help. I don´t know if it is because for Host-only I get dynamic ip from dhcp or something else. I just must set more settings for internet.

Comment: @Bibo Anything else is probably a configuration issue on the guest side. Make sure the guest can see the adapter (`ifconfig`), and take a look at the [FreeBSD documentation on adding a network adapter](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/config-network-setup.html). Win7/Kubuntu/OpenSUSE guests always detected the adapter automatically for me, but I've never used FreeBSD before.

Comment: Putting the NAT adapter first may help.

Answer (score 0):

For your guests have access the internet through "host-only", you need to have some firewall rules enabled. Full details on...

https://superuser.com/a/1238065/195840

**NOTE:** I did not answer completely your question here because in this way we will have a duplicate answer in the superuser.