# Local DNS Resolution Between Host Guest

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, dns

Inside vbox6.1 on an Ubuntu Desktop host. I have a software requirement for a host-only network adapter with internet access.  I was able to configure this and I can successfully ping the guest from the host and the guest has internet access via the host-only adapter.

I have one remaining problem, local dns resolution.

In order to get internet access to the guest I had to use ip MASQUERADE from the vboxnet0 address to the primary network interface of the host.

This caused one side effect. Although the guest has a bind9 server configured and runnng correctly, the host machine can only resolve IP address from the guest, not domain names.  For example

I can reach the guest's server control panel using:

`https://192.168.64.87:3080`

But I cannot not reach the server control panel using:

`https://test.example.com:3080`

The host machine has resolvconf installed, but it seems that ip Masquerade is causing   the content of the host machine's `/etc/hosts` file to **skipped / ignored** and attempts to directly resolve domains from public dns servers.

when I use `dig  example.com`  it shows that the dns of my production server is being utilized to try to resolve test.example.com which doesn't exist on the production server.

How can I force the host's machine's resolvconf (or another tool) to resolve domain names on the guest server so that I can view them in the host's web browser?

**Progress Update**
My host machine's /etc/resolv.conf has:

```
nameserver 192.168.61.2
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search hitronhub.home
```

where 192.168.61.2 is the ip address of the vboxnet0 dhcp server

I have also been some more research and installed dnsmasq as [recommended here](https://superuser.com/questions/1237463/virtualbox-host-only-with-internet)

Now, when I run `dig example.com` it does not show my productions nameserver.  It doesn't show any nameserver and fails.  (I have not fully configured dnsmasq yet)

Any tips appreciated

Comment: What's in the host machine's `/etc/resolv.conf`? How is the /etc/hosts file relevant to the problem?

Comment: @user1686  I just updated the post with info you wanted and my progress on the problem

Comment: @user1686 Thanks for your help I cracked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. The key thing here was to correctly configure dnsmasq to recognize the ip of my vbox guest's static ip for domain resolution.

I found clear [tutorial here](https://medium.com/soulweb-academy/docker-local-dev-stack-with-traefik-https-dnsmasq-locally-trusted-certificate-for-ubuntu-20-04-5f036c9af83d), but I made some small modifications, so I will show my steps below for others follow.

1. Disable & stop systemd resolved

   $ sudo systemctl disable systemd-resolved
   $ sudo systemctl stop systemd-resolved
2. Remove symlink on `/etc/resolv.conf` & remove the file

   $ ls -lh /etc/resolv.conf
   $ sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
3. Create a new /`etc/resolv.conf` with the following values:

   $ sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolv.conf' #(host machine resolution of doman names)

   $ sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" >> /etc/resolv.conf' #(public dns server ip for outside internet)

   $ sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 192.168.64.87" >> /etc/resolv.conf' #(virtualbox guest static ip address)
4. Install dnsmasq

   $ sudo apt install dnsmasq
5. Add .test to the dnsmasq config file:

   $ sudo bash -c 'echo "address=/.test/192.168.64.87" >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf'

**NOTE**: Folks developing wordpress multisites that need wildcard domain resolution can use:
$ sudo bash -c 'echo "address=/example.test/192.168.64.87" >> /etc/dnsmasq.conf'

6. Create a directory resolver for the guest's static ip address:

   $sudo mkdir -v /etc/resolver && sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 192.168.64.87" > /etc/resolver/test'
7. Restart dnsmasq and network-manager

   $ sudo systemctl restart dnsmasq
   $ sudo systemctl restart network-manager
8. Test your dnsmasq set-up

a.) open your browser and confirm that you still have outside internet access

b.) run `dig example.test` you should be able to seethe static ip address of your guest

c.) in your host machine's browser open example.test

That's it.